# Relative measurement error in addition / subtraction formula

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

if the Absolute Measurement Error = Wrong Value - Correct Value

> positive/negative sign is neglected since a posisitve calculation
> error is as bad as a negative calculation error.

and if the

***Relative Measurement Error*** = Absolute Measurement Error ÷ Correct Value

and the value is determind by adding or subtracting two different values. For example:

first   volume= 5. correct number was: 4.5 = (4.5±.5)

secound volume= 6. correct number was: 4   = (4±2)

Final Volume = Second Volume - First Volume.

What is the ***relative measurement error of the final volume*** in the previous calculation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to the community! I will ask you to rephrase your question to make it clearer, but this is what I understand from what you're asking.

When you add/subtract two quantities, each with an associated error, the errors add.

So you're calculating

Final Volume = First Volume + Second Volume = 5 + 6 = 11

Then the error associated with Final Volume is

Error in Final Volume = Error in First Volume + Error in Second Volume

Error in Final Volume = 0.5 + 2 = 2.5

So Final Volume is $11 \pm 2.5$.

The $\pm$ values you give are absolute errors. The relative error is usually given as a percentage. In your case:

Relative error = 2.5 / 11 = 22.7%

Comment: Can i change this problem from addition or subtraction to multiplication or division problem :

Suppose Area is calculated by multiblying lenght*width    ,
and the length = (6±.1) and ,  the width=(5±.2)  ,  
Then Area=6*5=30  ,  
Then Relative error in measring Area = Relative error in the first measurement+Relative error in the secound measurement  ,
=.1÷6   +  .2÷5
=0.017  +  0.04 =0.057    ,   

how can we calculat the absolute value in measring Area?

Comment: Yes you can! You have correctly calculated the relative error in the area, which is defined as Absolute Error in Area / Area. Multiple the relative error by Area to get the absolute error.

Comment: Why can't i just add the two absolute errors to get the final absolute error in the Area ,, why should i calculate the relative error then muliply it with the Area to get the absolute error ?

Comment: https://www.geol.lsu.edu/jlorenzo/geophysics/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html#muldiv provides the most straightforward proof. An intuitive answer is the fact that the units don't match: if I have a 0.1m uncertainty in Length 1, and a 0.2m uncertainty in Length 2, adding 0.1m + 0.2m = 0.3m. This is not m^2, the unit of area. So you need relative uncertainties to account for the fact that the units are different.

Comment: In the first "addition problem" you calculated the relative error by dividing the final error by the correct final value ,,, while in the second "multiplication problem" you calculated the relative error once for each measurement then adding those two relative errors together

Comment: Yes, addition/subtraction and multiplication/division must be treated separately when calculating error propagation. The first is best done with absolute errors, the second best done with relative errors.

Comment: You don't add errors  linearly.

Answer (score 0):

Uncorrelated errors add in quadrature, so if:

$$ V = V_1- V_2 $$

then

$$ \delta V^2 = \delta V_1^2 + \delta V_2^2$$

Thus:

$$ \delta V = \sqrt{0.5^2 + 2^2} = 2.06 $$

This is a special case of: If $z$ is some function of $x$ and $y$:

$$ z = f(x,y) $$

then

$$ \delta z^2 = \big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\delta x\big)^2 + \big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\delta y\big)^2 $$